# Filtering Pandas DataFrame based on number of non-null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, survey

I am analyzing a consumer survey and doing the data cleaning with Pandas. I have a question where participants could answer with what frequency they are confronted with ads ('Daily': 1, 'Multiple times a week': 2, 'Once a week':3, 'Once a year': 4, 'Never': 5).

If the participant would answer that they would see ads at least weekly (1,2,3) they would get a whole new line of questions based on the product categories whether they were confronted with them and how often. The survey system would not ask all of the categories but would randomize the survey so 4 categories were asked about. The DataFrame with the answers looks like this:

| Respondent ID | Question Frequency Ads | Question Product 1 | Question Product 2 | Question Product 3 | ... | Question Product 19 | Question Product 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  | 5 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |  | 3 |  | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |  | 5 | 3 |  | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 4 | 5 |  |  | 5 | 2 |

I therefore want to filter the respondents that filled in the questionnaire as it should. The respondents that answered that they are confronted at least weekly with ads, should have at least an answer for 4 product questions. I already tried the following code:

```
data = data[((data['Question Frequency Ads'].isin([1,2,3])) & (data['Question Product 1'].isnull() + data['Question Product 2'].isnull() + data['Question Product 3'].isnull() + ... + data['Question Product 20'].isnull())) == (20-4)]
```

I realize this code will not work because of the fact that when adding these boolean expressions, you just get a True/False value and no integer which shows how many True/False values there are. Can someone help me with getting the right expression for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

IIUC:

```
m1 = df['Question Frequency Ads'].le(3)
m2 = df.iloc[:, 2:].notna().sum(axis=1).ge(4)
out = df[~m1 | (m1 & m2)]
```

- `~m1`: if `Question Frequency Ads > 3`, we keep the respondent because he don't have to answer to questions.
- `m1 & m2`: if `Question Frequency Ads <= 3`, we keep the respondent only if he answered at least to 4 questions.

---

**Old answer**
You can use:

```
out = df[df['Question Frequency Ads'].le(3) & df.iloc[:, 2:].notna().sum(axis=1).ge(4)]
```

Output:

| Respondent ID | Question Frequency Ads | Question Product 1 | Question Product 2 | Question Product 3 | Question Product 19 | Question Product 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |  | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |  | 5 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 4 | 5 |  | 5 | 2 |

Comment: I would still need the first 2 respondents, they don't have a high frequency on the first question so they don't have to answer the other questions. My goal is to filter out those respondents who are frequently confronted with ads, but did not qnswer qt leqst 4 category questions.

Comment: I think I get it but I'm not sure :) Can you check it please. In fact, on your sample, we keep everyone.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try:

1. Keep all rows where Question Frequency Ads is in `[1, 2, 3]` *and*
2. Where the number of questions that have a response is exactly 4.

```
>>> >>> data[data["Question Frequency Ads"].isin([1,2,3]) & data.filter(like="Question Product").count(1).eq(4)]
```

Or:

```
>>> data[data["Question Frequency Ads"].isin([1,2,3]) & data.drop(["Respondent ID", "Question Frequency Ads"], axis=1).count(1).eq(4)]
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the question is not really called with 'Question Product...', it is just a sample. I should really make a list in the expression.

Comment: Then you can drop the non-question columns instead: `data.drop(["Respondent ID", "Question Frequency Ads"], axis=1).count(1).eq(4)`

Comment: the goal is to keep these ones as it is really the purpose to filter out the non-complete answers, so I cannot afford to filter out these columns.

Comment: This is just for the filter. You don't actually have to drop them. `drop` is not in place.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
m1 = df['Question Frequency Ads'].between(1,3)
m2 = df.filter(like='Question Product').notnull().sum(1).ge(4)

df.loc[m1&m2, 'valid'] = 'valid'
```

output:

```
   Respondent ID  Question Frequency Ads  Question Product 1  \
0              1                       5                 NaN   
1              2                       4                 NaN   
2              3                       2                 1.0   
3              4                       1                 1.0   
4              5                       1                 NaN   
5              5                       1                 4.0   

   Question Product 2  Question Product 3  ...  Question Product 19  \
0                 NaN                 NaN  NaN                  NaN   
1                 NaN                 NaN  NaN                  NaN   
2                 2.0                 3.0  NaN                  5.0   
3                 NaN                 3.0  NaN                  5.0   
4                 5.0                 3.0  NaN                  5.0   
5                 5.0                 NaN  NaN                  5.0   

   Question Product 20  valid  
0                  NaN    NaN  
1                  NaN    NaN  
2                  NaN  valid  
3                  2.0  valid  
4                  2.0  valid  
5                  2.0  valid
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the question is not really called with 'Question Product...', it is just a sample. I should really make a list in the expression.

Comment: @SDR3078 you can select by any other method, like position: `df.loc[2:]...`, or fixed list: `cols = ['A', 'B', 'C'] ; df[cols]...`, difference: `df.drop(columns=['Respondent ID', 'Question Frequency Ads'])...`

Comment: I think the `ge(df["Question Frequency Ads"])` should be changed to `eq(4)`. OP specifies "4 categories were asked about"

Comment: @not_speshal you're right, I thought the 1,2,3 was the number of times, but it doesn't make sense, thanks!

Comment: The first 2 should still be valid, they are not frequent visitors of ads so they dont have to answer the questions. Entries should be deleted if they frequently see ads AND did not answer exactly 4 questions

Comment: then use another mask ,or  XOR: `df.loc[m1^m2, 'valid'] = 'valid'`

Answer (score 0):

here is a different approach:

```
def is_int(x):
    try:
        int(x)
    except:
        return False
    return True

def is_valid(line):
    count = 0
    for el in line[2:]:
        if is_int(el):
            count+=1
    return count == 4

df[df[df['Question Frequency Ads'].between(1,3)].apply(is_valid, axis=1)]
```